# Links aren't clickable

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am making a web app here http://repinzle.herokuapp.com

For some reason the links can't be clicked, this is very frustrating and confusing.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element with id `gallery` Has a `z-index` of -10, putting it below its container, `main`.

Comment: I've removed z-index from gallery and given the element that I wanted to "float on top" a positive z-index. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no source defined:

[image]

Put a url after the href.

```
href="http://www.TheUrl.com"
```

[Here is a full example.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: Thanks Kassy, I think the main issue was related to the z-index, but of course you need a href value to make a link do something ;)

Comment: This isn't the crux of the issue, in any decent modern browser they're still clickable (much better than littering with hashes, although neither as good as properly anchoring I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

I just gave this div:

```
<div id="gallery" style="z-index: -10; position: relative; display: block;z-index: 1;">
```

a z-index:1. I can't explain the problem, but this maybe solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspected the code:

```
<div id="gallery" style=" position: relative; display: block;">
```

Has a style of Z-index: -10, remove it and it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your url(/salon/tickle-me) is correct

The href attribute specifies the link's destination:

```
<a href="http://www.URL.com">TicKle me</a>
```